# Jobs search should be able to search in the whole of European Union

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

The EU has a unique enough case that its citizens can freely work in any of its countries. For example, I would be open to working anywhere in Europe but I don't want to move to another continent or deal with protracted visa and permit issues. However, if I want to find a job in the EU, I have to search every country separately. It's as if you would be unable to search the whole of the United States and had to search each state separately.

I would propose that the Jobs search would understand that when searching for the European Union or EU, it should search all of the constituent countries.

Comment: Do you *really* want to see jobs where the primary requirement is to be fluent in, say, Italian or Greek?

Comment: @HansPassant *Is* being fluent in Italian or Greek, or whatever language  the primary requirement for most jobs that are posted in StackOverflow? Besides most Europeans know at least a couple of languages.

Comment: Being able to effectively communicate with the team members is in general a strong requirement, yes.  The odds that the company switches to Latvian or English to accommodate a new hire are low.  Knowing several languages is good but you'd still go shopping for jobs that match the languages you actually know.  Which essentially is the way it already works.

Comment: @HansPassant Companies are quite desperate for tech workers nowadays, and they are quite open to using English, at least the ones searching for people on StackOverflow. I've gotten offers from numerous EU countries and none of them insisted on fluency in their [non-English] language.

Comment: @HansPassant In fact, perusing the jobs section, *which is what we're discussing*, I couldn't find any EU job offers that weren't written in English *or* that required fluency in any [non-programming] language.

Answer (score 6):

Great point and valid use case. We'll be looking into adding this in. I'll set the status to deferred for now.