# Don't limit job searching in EU

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

The following moderator comment has been made on [Search jobs by Location does not work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314337/search-jobs-by-location-does-not-work)

> We've had employers that were getting applications from outside of their region or country that they simply cannot act upon - either due to not allowing remote or because they don't provide visa sponsorship. If an employer checks the 'visa sponsorship' button on the job then it is, by default (the employer can change it), visible worldwide. Obviously this becomes an issue for those travelling, but we considered that enough of an edge case to not worry about it.... – Dean Ward♦

Also, [Jobs search should be able to search in the whole of European Union](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312849/jobs-search-should-be-able-to-search-in-the-whole-of-european-union) is related, but I would like to touch on another aspect of the problem here.

I think region or country is implemented in a way too strict manner here. [Besides the points Stephan already mentions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314468/5324371), I would like to explain my own (frustrating) situation, and I can't possibly be the only one with this problem.

I live on the border of Belgium, in Netherlands. Being from the EU, I automatically have a work permit for every EU country, including the neighbouring one. Both Antwerp and Ghent are no more than a 30 minute drive for me. The closest Dutch city (much smaller than Antwerp and Ghent) is about an hour drive and on the other end of a toll tunnel. Guess where I would like to look for work? That's right, Belgium. Yet a search for jobs in Belgium only returns 1 result, while Netherlands returns 127. Most of these jobs (actually all but 1) are over 2 hours away from me, even.

Although my situation is perhaps a bit extreme, there are many people living close to the border and able to work abroad too, especially in the EU.

I would be happy if I could see jobs in Belgium (or any EU country for that matter) within a certain distance from me, and I think this is not unreasonable, or perhaps that I could indicate that I am interested in jobs in a different country instead.

Comment: I live on the French border near Germany. Switzerland is not too far away. While I'm currently a student, this issue does not affect me as of right now. However, it will soon. And would be furstrating if I couldn't see German job offers (seeing that Germany is literally a 10 minute drive away).

Comment: @Hans Too often doesn't work. I live [here](https://goo.gl/maps/ApCgdjJAui92) and could step on a plane and start working a job [here](https://goo.gl/maps/GuWps2j34DP2) (4200 miles from where I live) tomorrow but not [here](https://goo.gl/maps/YGTBVN5mARs) (60 miles.) The EU and other areas with automatic cross-border work permits need special treatment

Comment: @HansPassant but the problem is that the system is actively *hiding* job adverts from you if you're not in the right country because of permit-to-work problems. To even *see* the advert from Antwerp, a user in the Netherlands would have to subscribe to a VPN service  with a Belgian endpoint, and then search again. Not impossible, but a little much to ask. No?

Answer (score 36):

Totally agreed. Hiding job listings from visitors from countries whose citizens have an *automatic* right to work in the country the job is in seems insane.

Ultimately, it will lead to fewer suitable candidates seeing employers's jobs.

Answer (score 11):

An excellent way around this that could easily be implemented in 6-8 weeks is giving users the ability to specify the countries where they are legally entitled to work.  I would love the ability to look for work in England, and all of the EU, although I currently live in Canada, since I am legally entitled to work there.

Comment: definitely the best option. Inferring work permission from the IP address or any non-specified source seems rather odd when you think about it.

Comment: Wish I had 100 accounts to upvote this, but I only have 1.